# not able to reference Angular Cli generated scripts and css in home.cshtml instead of default index.html in .NET Core Angular cli spa template

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp-net-core-spa-services

I am stuck with the problem to upgrade my existing template from Angular 4.0.3 to Angular 6.1 in .NET core 2.2 template using Visual studio 2017.

Here are the details below

- Visual studio 2017
- Angular Cli with Angular 6.1.0
- Angular spa template with .NET Core 2.2

As per the default template structure https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/ProjectTemplates/Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates/content/Angular-CSharp it also uses the default index.html.

I am having some trouble to reference the generated css and js files. I need to use the cshtml file for Home controller with `_Layout` instead of the default `index.html` that comes with the template. `Home.cshtml` will contain the root component of the Angular project. But I am not sure how to link the css and js files generated by the template during runtime in the cshtml page. Those css and js files are generated by webpack when we start the app by F5 as it creates a separate instance of the Angular cli server (`ng serve`), but those files are not visible in the solution.

Similarly I need to provide link of those files during `dotnet publish` in the production build and deployment.`(ng build --prod)`.

Can you please help as I am stuck with the problem to upgrade existing template from Angular 4.0.3 to Angular 6.1 in .NET core 2.2 template.Earlier template was using **webpackmiddleware and hot reload** to separately generate this files but now it’s part of Angular cli.

P.S I was following this article https://medium.com/@waelkdouh/how-to-update-visual-studio-asp-net-core-angular-project-to-the-latest-version-25de32cfeb84

for the set up but my requirement is to reference them in Razor view page/_Layout instead of the default index.html